# use filter, limitTo with begin in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-limitto

I want to implement search & pagination as easily as possible using default angular features as Angular 1.4 now has begin parameter in limitTo filter.

Desired functionality :

- Search from all items in array
- implement pagination using limitTo filter

Issue : if we add begin in limitTo i.e. `limitTo : 5 : 2` the search functionality breaks.

here's a plnkr 
http://plnkr.co/Lk2TfkMoZKVbj4MH4U0G

how can we make search work while using begin in limitTo filter.

Comment: It does work. Its just that you dont have any results to show when you say that start with 2 and limit to 5. Check this updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/1B5gxKvPDwvOflQV5efq?p=preview

Comment: @NiravGandhi `limitTo:2:5` means  show from index 2 to 7 in ng-repeat right? this works fine without search. If we remove begin, we can search from all items in array but can't at all search if we add a begin number.

Comment: If we search House which is at index 4, it should show up right? but it doesn't. maybe I'm making some stupid mistake..

Comment: yo .. as per your code.. it first searches and then puts limit logic. Your search for house gets 1 result but since u do limitTo : 5 : 2, it gets lost.

Comment: @NiravGandhi ok great